# Chrome Extension Automatically Pull and Store Data

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Pretend I have a chrome extension that has a word of the day. Each day I have a new word and my extension highlights that word on any page loaded in the browser that day. I could have a rotating list of words, but I want to maintain that list on my website so I can easily change it based on news or current events.

How could I make my extension get the contents of a file on my server every X hours and save that as a variable for future use?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep something like a timer for requests in a [background.js](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages). 
As Daniel suggested, easiest way to do that is using the [chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms) API.

For example:

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "alarms",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(alarm => {
    fetch('http://your_website_here')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(textResponse => {
            chrome.storage.local.set({data: textResponse});
        })
        .catch(e => {console.error(e)})
});

chrome.alarms.create('fetch_data', {
    periodInMinutes: 60 //every hour
});
```

I suggest you to use the [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) API, to store your data. You can retrieve it later from content-script.